# Hide Div From those who visit directly to the page but don't who refer from a exact domain using php

Tags: php, post-redirect-get

I want to hide a div from direct users but showing the same div to those who come from example.com

eg.
     example123.com/article.php have below div

```
<div id="main">Title</div>
```

(when user click on a hyperlink on example.com

```
<a href="http://example123.com/article.php">Artile</a>
```

then show the above div

but when user come directly to example123.com/article.php then don't show the div.

how will I do that using php?

Comment: Is the link to your article.php page internal or external? If it's internal, then you have control over the link and add parameters so that you can use $_GET. But if you want to detect if the user is coming from an external site's link that you don't control, that's a different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use the following code like this.

```
 <?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){ ?>
      <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid black">
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by passing an argument from the URL. The value of the argument will be null if they access the page directly and only have a value if they use the specific URL. Then your PHP can just check the argument and handle it accordingly.

Example as follows.

```
index.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Nothing</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Nothing 01</h1>
<a href="pagewithdiv.php">Regular URL</a>
<br />
<a href="pagewithdiv.php?Condition=true">Argument URL</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Then you can handle the Arguments in your PHP page containing the div

```
pagewithdiv.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Nothing</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Nothing 02</h1>

<div id="conditional">
   <h2>Conditional Div</h2>
</div>

<?php
if (

   // check if argument exists
   isset($_GET["Condition"])
   &&
   // check if argument value is true
   trim($_GET["Condition"] == true)

) {

   echo '<script>';
   echo 'document.getElementById("conditional").style.display = "block"';
   echo '</script>';

} else {

   echo '<script>';
   echo 'document.getElementById("conditional").style.display = "none"';
   echo '</script>';

}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Keep in mind though that this is only hiding the div, it still exists on the page. If you want it to be completely gone then instead of using javascript to change the visibility you can echo the code that makes up the div if the requirements are met.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Nothing</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Nothing 02</h1>

<?php
if (

   // check if argument exists
   isset($_GET["Condition"])
   &&
   // check if argument value is true
   trim($_GET["Condition"] == true)

) {

   echo '<div id="conditional">';
   echo '   <h2>Conditional Div</h2>';
   echo '</div>';


}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you write in example code for me coz i am very beginner in php.

Comment: Sure but in the meanwhile you should take a look at the answer by @Chris because it is probably better suited for your needs

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

I don't totally follow your question but this code should be enough for you to adapt to your needs:

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'example.com')) {
  echo '<div id="main">Title</div>';
}
```

So, if the referrer URL contains example.com then echo your div.

If the referral URL didn't contain example.com or was empty (i.e. they arrived directly at your site) then the div won't show.

Comment: its generate the error [16-Dec-2017 00:00:03 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER